# Check the convergence of a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a bounded sequence such that $a_{n+1} > a_{n} - 1/2^{n}$ check the convergence of the sequence.

$a_{n+1} > a_{n} - 1/2^{n}$

$ a_{n} - a_{n+1} < 1/2^{n}$

This doesn't conclude anything.

Hint is given to consider a sequence $b_{n} = a_{n} - 1/2^{n-1}$

How to proceed$?$

Comment: What is the relation between $b_{n + 1}$ and $b_n$? Your knowledge of something about $a_{n + 1}$ and $a_n$ can be translated to something about $b_{n + 1}$ and $b_n$.

Comment: Difference between both terms is $a_{n+1} - a_{n} + 1/2^{n}$

Comment: That's correct. Now try to use the given inequality and find an inequality for $b_{n + 1}$ and $b_n$.

Comment: $b_{n}$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Different way: What can you say about $\limsup a_n - \liminf a_n$?

Comment: I think you should have seen a result that a bounded monotone sequence is convergent.

Comment: $b_{n}$ is bounded since $a_{n}$ and $1/2^{n-1}$ is bounded... Okay I got it! Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer. How do we find this difference$?$

Comment: By using estimates for it. If $m > n$, then $a_m > a_n - 1/2^{n-1}$. Now take an $n$ such that $a_n$ is close to the $\limsup$, say $a_n > \limsup a_k - \varepsilon$. It follows that the difference is at most $\varepsilon + 2^{1-n}$. Since you can choose $\varepsilon > 0$ as small as you like, and $n$ arbitrarily large, the difference must be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you were really close when you noted that

$$a_n-a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and let $N$ be the smallest natural such that

$$\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}<\epsilon$$

Let $n$ and $m$ be naturals such that $m\geq n\geq N$. Then

$$|a_n-a_m|=|(a_n-a_{n+1})+(a_{n+1}-a_{n+2})+(a_{n+2}-a_{n+3})+\cdots+(a_{m-1}-a_m)|$$

$$\leq |a_n-a_{n+1}|+|a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}|+\cdots+|a_{m-1}-a_m|$$

$$<\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}=\sum_{i=n}^{m-1}\frac{1}{2^i}<\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}\leq \sum_{i=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}<\epsilon.$$

Thus, $a_n$ is a [Cauchy Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#In_real_numbers) and therefore converges.